Mystery part identification on a UMX Conscendo controller
I could use some help identifying this part labeled “33.0C 3824”.
The logo looks like it could be the old Cypress logo. Any help would be appreciated.


Please provide dimensions

Did you mean "Conscendo"? That looks like a close-up of this board. Based on its position on the board and the components around it, I'll bet that it's the voltage regulator for the logic on the board.

There is a dot indicating pin 1. There is no logo.

It's probably a SCT SCT2330C step-down converter. The markings don't have a dot, but everything else seems to match. The image looks like a heavily processed smart phone picture, so the dot might be just an artifact.


(Source: lcsc.com)
